# Intuition behind data preprocessing in ML

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, normalization

I'm going through [CS231n](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/2017/syllabus) to understand the basics of neural networks.

Attached is the slide in which Justin (the tutor) gives the reasoning for why data preprocessing is required and I don't completely understand. The explanation given is similar to the one given on the slide and I don't get it. The slide is below.

[image: Slide from CS231N]

The second question I have is: is it actually normalisation or standardisation? This link implies that it is [standardisation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10298/280765), whereas the course material says it is [normalisation](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#datapre).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) The meaning of "less sensitive to small changes in weights" can easily be visualized. Imagine to operate a little change in the weights of the drawn hyperplane, i.e. rotate it a bit. If the samples are located around the origin, you'll notice that they can still be correctly classified. If they're far away from the origin, the same little change in weights will lead to bigger misclassifications.
[image]

B) Sometimes standardization and normalization are used interchangeably.

**Standardization**: I quote from Machine Learning and Pattern Recognition by Bishop : *"For the purposes of this example, we have made a linear re-scaling of the data, known as standardizing, such that each of the variables has zero mean and unit standard deviation."*

**Normalization** could be e.g. min-max normalization when you scale all feature values to the [0,1] range, or feature vector normalization when you divide the feature vector by its modulus.

Comment: For A, I still don't understand, maybe I can't visualise it well enough.  If I move the hyperplane before or after normalisation, the classification should still look the same right?

Comment: I added a poorly drawn image ;D

Comment: If it can't be illustrated with a poorly drawn image, it can't be illustrated.